# Does Facebook messenger SDK allow to transfer money from App?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, messenger

Since Facebook messenger allows for the movement of money to debit cards,some folks will be logging into App via Facebook, could be make the money movement capability through fb messenger?
There is no cost to move money via messenger. We could have people move money to other Debit card this way ?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Could I login through via messanger and able to send money from card to card in my App

Comment: You can use messenger to send money yes

Comment: How? How could I send money via Facebook messanger

Comment: You go to Messenger and send money to someone

Comment: Can we use it same in messanger  Ios SDK ??

Comment: No there is no sdk